# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Кто что ест", и поясните, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении:

> Кто что ест.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна. Мы её ставим перед союзом "что", служебной частью речи. А здесь "что" — это местоимение, в данном предложении оно является дополнением и не приходится ничему однородным, так что нет ни одной причины для запятой.